# Core Data: Defining common functions to control Core Data

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I am using the default PersistenceController file provided by Xcode:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newMessage = Message(context: viewContext)
            newMessage.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Chat")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
```

Then I inject the shared viewContext as it is done by default:

```
@main
struct GPT_SandboxApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

But then how do I define functions related to Core Data which I can use in different Views? I want to have functions such as "deleteMessages" and "addMessage" but creating them in the PersistenceController won't work since only viewContext is passed to the child Views. Creating them in the View itself (how it's done in the default project) seems not rigorous to me because you'd have to copy these functions in every View you need them.

I feel like ideally passing the whole PersistenceController object to all child views is a better idea, but I haven't found any such examples

I know I can just define functions in a separate file like this:

```
func deleteMessages(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Message.fetchRequest()

    do {
        if let fetchedMessages = try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Message] {
            for message in fetchedMessages {
                viewContext.delete(message)
            }
            try viewContext.save()
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error deleting all messages: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

But when you use them like `deleteMessages(viewContext)` it's ambiguous - what messages am I deleting, the ones from Core Data? Or maybe other messages that I store in a local variable, or something else?
If it was written like `persistenceController.deleteMessages()` that would be quite clear.

Please share your approaches to handling this

Comment: If `deleteMessages(...)` has one argument, and that argument is an `NSManagedObjectContext`, it's not really ambiguous what messages you're deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we put them in a `NSManagedObjectContext` extension or if it's for a specific object then in the `NSManagedObject` class or extension.